# Exponential RV conditional expectation E[X|X<t]

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

For an exponential RV with mean $\mu$, we know that $E[X\mid X>t]$ is $t + \mu$. But how can you compute $E[X\mid X < t]$?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\mu = \operatorname{E}(X) & = \operatorname{E}(X\mid X<t)\Pr(X<t) + \operatorname{E}(X\mid X>t)\Pr(X>t) \\[10pt]
& = \operatorname{E}(X\mid X<t)(1-e^{-t/\mu}) + (t+\mu) e^{-t\mu}.
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\operatorname{E}(X\mid X<t) = \frac{\mu - (t+\mu)e^{-t/\mu}}{1 - e^{-t/\mu}}.
$$

(We need not consider the event $X=t$ since its probability is $0$.)